# using implictilyWait with Webdriver

Tags: selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

lib-  selenium-java2.0rc2.jar and selenium-server-standalone-2.-b3.jar

simple test:

```
webDriver = new FirefoxDriver();
webDriver.get("http://www.google.com");
webDriver.findElement(By.name("q")).sendKeys("Test");
webDriver.findElement(By.name("btnG")).click();

Assert.assertTrue(webDriver.findElement(By.cssSelector("ol#rso>li:nth-child(1) a"))
            .getText().equalsIgnoreCase("Test.com Web Based Testing and Certification Software v2.0"));
```

Assertion fails, and then I added *BAD* wait statement, just before asserition -

```
Thread.sleep(3000);
Assert.assertTrue(webDriver.findElement(By.cssSelector("ol#rso>li:nth-child(1) a"))
.getText().equalsIgnoreCase("Test.com Web Based Testing and Certification Software v2.0"));
```

Test succeeds. 
But then came across implicitlyWait and used it as -

```
webDriver = new FirefoxDriver();

webDriver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

webDriver.get("http://www.google.com");
webDriver.findElement(By.name("q")).sendKeys("Test");
webDriver.findElement(By.name("btnG")).click();
Assert.assertTrue(webDriver.findElement(By.cssSelector("ol#rso>li:nth-child(1) a"))
.getText().equalsIgnoreCase("Test.com Web Based Testing and Certification Software v2.0"));
```

Assertion again fails, looks like implicitlyWait() does not have any impact here. And I definitely don't want to use Thread.sleep(). What could be the possible solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use webdriverwait class to wait for an expected condition to come true.

```
     ExpectedCondition e = new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>() {
          public Boolean apply(WebDriver d) {
            //Wait until text changes
                    return webDriver.findElement(By.cssSelector("ol#rso>li:nth-child(1) a"))
                    .getText().equalsIgnoreCase("Test.com Web Based Testing and Certification Software v2.0"));
          }
        };

        Wait w = new WebDriverWait(driver, 60);
        w.until(e);

    //do asserts now
    Assert.assertTrue(...);
```